# Como ordenar registros na consulta de acordo com outra ordenação?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho uma tabela com as seguintes colunas:

id - id_gerencial - valor - origem - id_origem

Ao cadastrar um "Conta a Pagar", insiro nessa tabela desmembramentos gerenciais da empresa. Supondo que precisaria pagar para um determinado fornecedor o valor de 600,00 dividido em 3 parcelas de 200,00, e esse valor ser desmembrado para os seguintes setores gerenciais: "RH", "ADMINISTRATIVO" e "ALMOXARIFADO". Minha tabela ficaria com os seguintes valores:

1 - 5 - 150,00 - P - 1

2 - 8 - 250,00 - P - 1

3 - 4 - 200,00 - P - 1

Quando vou fazer a quitação da primeira parcela, faço um rateio dos gerenciais para o movimento de contas, e insiro na mesma tabela os seguintes valores:

4 - 5 - 50,00 - M - 1

5 - 8 - 83,33 - M - 1

6 - 4 - 66,67 - M - 1

Ou seja, tanto os desmembramentos do cadastro do documento principal (Conta a Pagar), quanto os da quitação, ficam na mesma tabela.

Quando for quitar a segunda parcela, os valores de rateio serão os mesmos citados anteriormente, pois o valor da parcela é a mesma.

Agora quando for quitar a terceira (última) parcela, não posso fazer o devido rateio porque se fizer, a soma total dos rateios poderá ser diferente do valor desmembrado no documento principal (Conta a Pagar). Para resolver isso, preciso fazer a soma de todos os gerenciais quitados e subtrair do principal. Então para fazer a última quitação, é necessário fazer duas consultas. A primeira consulta vai me trazer os valores quando cadastrado, ordenado por código ficaria algo do tipo:

```
SELECT
 id_gerencial,
 valor
FROM
 desmembramento
WHERE
 origem = 'P'
ORDER BY
 id;
```

Essa consulta me retorna:

5 - 150,00

8 - 250,00

4 - 200,00

Para continuar, tenho uma segunda consulta, que é a somatória das quitações agrupando pelas contas gerenciais:

```
SELECT
 id_gerencial,
 SUM(valor) AS soma
FROM
 desmembramento
WHERE
 origem = 'M'
GROUP BY
 id_gerencial;
```

Acontece que essa consulta por não ter uma ordenação, não retorna na mesma ordem de quando cadastrado o documento principal, retornando algo do tipo:

4 - 133,34

8 - 166,66

5 - 100,00

Como faço a segunda consulta vir na mesma ordem dos gerenciais quando foram cadastrados?

Poderia ter simplificado mais a explicação, mas fui escrevendo do meu jeito para entender melhor.

---

EDITADO!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: colocar um `order by id` no fim do segundo select não resolveria o problema da ordenação?

Comment: Não porque uso uma função de agregação, pra funcionar teria que colocar o id no "Group By" também, mas para o que preciso não posso adicionar, tem que ser agrupado somente pelo "id_gerencial".

Comment: Poderia editar sua pergunta mostrando todas as tabelas e seus respectivos campos relacionados a tabela desmembramento? E descrever o que seria este processo de rateio? Sobre o order by, já utilizei ele juntamente com o group by, e realmente é necessário colocar o campo no agrupamento, porém quando tive que fazer isso não tive a query comprometida.

Comment: Coloquei um diagrama pra dar uma facilitada... a tabela que insiro registros para "Conta a Pagar" e "Movimento de Conta" é a "desmembramento". O processo de rateio é quando tenho um valor integral e preciso fazer uma divisão proporcional.

Comment: O rateio seria rastrear os registros de todas as parcelas daquela conta específica?

Comment: Não, o rateio é:  ((parcela_valor / conta_pagar_valor) * desmembramento_valor)). Caso alguém tiver interesse em ajudar, me adicione no Skype para que possa explicar melhor o que faço e como preciso ordenar uma consulta. Skype: polianomartini

Comment: Grave o saldo e o valor de baixa de cada parcela , se o saldo for menor que x centavos zere o saldo , uma trigger pode fazer isto.

Answer (score 1):

Se o order by não funciona com o group by, isso deve funcionar:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
   id_gerencial,
   SUM(valor) AS soma
  FROM
   desmembramento
  WHERE
   origem = 'M'
  GROUP BY
   id_gerencial
) ORDER BY id_genrencial;
```

Answer (score 0):

Por que você não coloca tudo numa consulta só?
Criei algo parecido com o seu cenário e consegui chegar ao resultado usando:

```
select
    d1.id_gerencial,
    d1.valor as valor_a_ratear,
    (select sum(d2.valor) from desmembramento as d2 where d2.id_origem = d1.id_origem and d2.id_gerencial = d1.id_gerencial and d2.origem = 'M') as valor_quitado,
    d1.valor - (select sum(d2.valor) from desmembramento as d2 where d2.id_origem = d1.id_origem and d2.id_gerencial = d1.id_gerencial and d2.origem = 'M') as valor_aberto
from
    desmembramento as d1
where
    d1.origem = 'P';
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta consulta retorna o valor total e a soma das parcelas pagas para cada `id_gerencial`:

```
select id_gerencial, dp.valor as valor_P, sum(dm.valor) as valor_M
from
    desmembramento dp
    inner join
    desmembramento dm using (id_gerencial, id_origem)
where dp.origem = 'P' and dm.origem = 'M'
group by 1, 2
order by 1
```

Mas ela depende de o `id_origem` ser o mesmo para todas os movimentos daquela conta a pagar. Mas eu não entendi o `id_origem` já que ele não aparece no esquema postado e eu desconfio que ele tem outro significado. Se não for o mesmo será necessário incluir o `id_conta_pagar` no `desmembramento`